# node js Calling stored procedure in mysql using connection pool and multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user : 'xxxxx',
  password : 'xxxxx',
  database : 'xxxx'
})
module.exports = connection;
```

customer.js

```
const db = require("../../db");
```

in customer.js i need to call a SP of mysql which will take 10 input parameters as it will insert a record in table.
What will be the best way to call SP from customer.js using db.js function

Answer (score 0):

I will create db class like this

```
let pool;

async function setConnectionPool() {
  if (!pool) {
    pool = await sql.connect("connectionstring here");
  }

  sql.on("error", err => {
    logger.error("An error has occured while setting connection pool", err);
    throw error;
  });
}

async function save(entity) {
  try {
    await pool.request()
      .input("SomeId1", sql.VarChar(50), entity.field1)
      .execute("SomeProcedureName");
  } catch (error) {
     console.log("error", error);
  }
}

module.exports = save;
```

From your customer.js you could simply call the method `save`

Hope this helps.